# how to create a formula for finding my net salary?

Tags: algorithm, math, formulas

Example : 
My Net salary is 3000 and deduction percentage is 0.0575. So my deduction is (3000*0.0575) = 172.5 and my take home is (3000-172.5 = 2827.5)

Now in the above case i know only the take home value (2827.5) and deduction percentage (0.0575) . How to create formula for getting my net salary??

Comment: `TH = (1 - DP) * NS <-> NS = TH / (1 - DP)`

Comment: @BeyelerStudios yes, duh.  typo...  (had the names backwards). I deleted comment.

Answer (score 2):

Net_sal=take_home/(1-deduction_rate)

Comment: Hi thank for your answer but by using above formula . I am getting 2999.44 and after round off it gives 2999. I need exact value of 3000

Comment: Then get the ceil value, rather rounding off